# Resetting a LDAP user's password in PHP, without the old password, using admin user

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I am trying to figure out how to reset a LDAP user password when connected as another user (admin user) in PHP for a password reset feature.

```
$this->con = ldap_connect($this->server);
ldap_set_option($this->con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

$user_search = ldap_search($this->con, $this->dn,"(|(uid=$user)(mail=$user))");
$this->user_get = ldap_get_entries($this->con, $user_search);
$user_entry = ldap_first_entry($this->con, $user_search);
$this->user_dn = ldap_get_dn($this->con, $user_entry);
$this->user_id = $this->user_get[0]["uid"][0];

$entry = array();
$entry["userPassword"] = "$encoded_newPassword";    
ldap_modify($this->con, $this->user_dn, $entry)
```

(aggregated from class methods) This works for resetting a user's password using the old password, but how would you go about doing a password change with another user (admin in this case)?

I think there is something about the LDAP authentication/binding that I am not understanding. Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction.

can I do a ldap_bind before the ldap_modify that will allow me to use user_dn and update the user as the admin user?

Not clear on how this all works.

OpenLDAP is the implementation being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [ldap_bind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php) with the dn/password of your admin user to establish the connection as this (admin) user.

Sample from the PHP manual

```
// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn  = 'uname';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'password';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap.example.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}
```